# How do I restart phusion passenger?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, mod-rails

```
rails@george:/srv/fsg_distro$ sudo passenger-status
*** Phusion Passenger: no passenger_native_support.so found for the current Ruby interpreter. Compiling one...
# mkdir -p /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.0/ext/ruby/ruby-1.8.7-x86_64-linux
# cd /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.0/ext/ruby/ruby-1.8.7-x86_64-linux
# /usr/bin/ruby '/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.0/ext/ruby/extconf.rb'
checking for alloca.h... yes
checking for ruby/io.h... no
creating Makefile
# make
gcc -I. -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.0/ext/ruby -DHAVE_ALLOCA_H    -fPIC -g -O2   -g  -c /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.0/ext/ruby/passenger_native_support.c
gcc -shared -o passenger_native_support.so passenger_native_support.o -L. -L/usr/lib -Wl,-R/usr/lib -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic    
ERROR: Phusion Passenger doesn't seem to be running.
```

My set up was working just fine but for some reason the last time I deployed it killed phusion passenger and I'm not sure how to restart it.  Any ideas?

I am running passenger as an apache module (mod rails).  I have tried restarting apache and rebooting the server with no luck.

Thanks

Comment: The wording of the title is misleading. You're not trying to restart passenger--you're trying to repair a broken installation. "Restart" has connotations of daemon management.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This thread](http://groups.google.com/group/phusion-passenger/browse_thread/thread/c0e597032d0c0df3/f1053ff2581032cf?show_docid=f1053ff2581032cf&pli=1) and the initial error you're getting from `passenger-status` suggest something's wrong with your Passenger installation - missing libraries which need to be compiled. Is reinstalling Passenger a realistic troubleshooting step here?

(edited to actually suggest something useful :)

Comment: Yes I did try that.  Sorry for not being clear in the question.  I updated it

Comment: I could do that, just weird that this was working perfectly until my last deployment.

Comment: Your answer is right.  I noticed there were two version of passenger installed.  Uninstalled both and reinstalled.  Works perfectly.  I guess bundler installed a new version when I deployed.  That's the only thing I can think of.  Thanks

Comment: Hi I have the same error. There is only one passenger 3.0.9 installed. Re-installation yielded no luck. Exactly the same error. Any thoughts about the problem?